# c++ design pattern to avoid copying and downcast

Tags: c++

I have a C++ class that holds a large piece of data.

```
class obj {
 public:
   obj(data_t data) : large_data(data) {}

 private:
   data_t large_data;
};
```

and a sub-class that augments the large piece of data with an immutable address value called `pos`. The basic idea is that an `obj` initially doesn't have a position but after some time may be given a position that never changes.

```
class safe_obj : public obj {
  public:
    safe_obj(int pos, data_t data) :
       obj(data), pos(pos)
    {}

    int pos() const { return pos; }

 private:
  int pos;
};
```

Up until now I've been creating instances of `obj` OR instances of `safe_obj`. What I'd like to be able to do is have a nice way to take an existing `obj` instance and assign it a position while minimizing any data movement.

My initial thought was to change my code to always allocate `safe_obj` and then pass around pointers to either one type or the other. When it came time to assign a position, the instance would have that space allocated already.

This approach would seem to require some type of `SetPos` interface, which I want to avoid to strictly enforce the immutability of the position.

Another option would be to store `obj::large_data` on the heap, and pass the pointer to a brand new instance of `safe_obj` when needed.

Are there other options?

Comment: A simple, `position_value_exists` bool set/get could unify the types and prevent any special copying.  Once the position is set, you don't allow another assign for the mutability part.  Not as language elegant as I'm sure others will come up with, but it should work.  Having the position value as a pointer or a known "not in use" value could double as the bool check if space is a concern.

Comment: thanks for the comment. i'm definitely trying to do something at the language level, but i'll add this to the list of possible real world solutions!

Comment: I think Michael's solution is probably as good as any. If you change object types you have to destroy and deallocate the old, allocate and initialise the new and replace the old. Allocations aren't the cheapest operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want `SetPos` interface because position can be set only once, you could use `InitPos` interface. The function name is selfexplaining, on second call it generates an error.

As another option you could use `obj` in `safe_obj` as a class member not as a base class, but this will affect cache locality as `pos` and `large_data` wouldn't be next to each other.

Comment: thanks. this is basically the approach i finally took. i was hoping for a pattern that would use the language to really enforce call sites being immutable vs non-immutable.